# Using C# lambdas to combine List<int> and int

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following list of Pair objects:

```
var listOfPairs = new List<Pair<int, List<int>>>() {
    new Pair<int, List<int>>(30, new List<int>() {3, 6, 9}),
    new Pair<int, List<int>>(40, new List<int>() {4, 8, 12})
};
```

I would like to end up with the following list of list-of-integers:

```
listOfPairs[0] = {30, 3, 6, 9};
listOfPairs[1] = {40, 4, 8, 12};
```

I've tried a lot of fiddling that looks like this, but to no avail:

```
var flattenedListOfPairs = listOfPairs.Select(pair => new List<int>(pair.First).AddRange(pair.Second));
```

I assume that what I'm trying to do is possible, and I'm just missing something.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `SelectMany()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you a list of lists, in the form you specified:

```
listOfPairs.Select(p => new []{ p.First }.Concat(p.Second).ToList()).ToList()
```

Comment: @AspNyc Be aware that if you drop the first call of `ToList`, the elements of the result list will be `IEnumerable<int>` rather than lists.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that, too.  =P  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you might want something like:

```
var flattened = listOfPairs.Select(pair => new[] { pair.First }.Concat(pair.Second)
                                                               .ToList())
                           .ToList();
```

Or:

```
var flattened = listOfPairs.Select(pair => Enumerable.Repeat(pair.First, 1)
                                                     .Concat(pair.Second)
                                                     .ToList())
                           .ToList();
```

Or using [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com)

```
var flattened = listOfPairs.Select(pair => pair.Second.Prepend(pair.First)
                                                      .ToList())
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Jon, I love your MoreLINQ library more than you'll ever know. I'm surprised a lot of these methods haven't been added into the framework, although there's a few I know have no chance of being added. IMO, Concat is the best choice here, as Union would eliminate the "first" number if it already exists in the collection.

Comment: waldrumpus gets the answer b/c he posted first, but I'm voting your comment for spelling out multiple approaches to my problem and introducing me to MoreLINQ.  tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

Other answers already covered how to do this, so I won't repeat that here. This answer is to explain why your existing code wasn't working. You expected to pass an int to the List constructor and have it initialize the List with that int. That's not how the constructor works. The List constructor uses the int argument to set up the initial size of the list, rather than set the value of any items.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still new enough to C# that I try to pass data to the constructor when I actually intend to use the object initialization syntax (e.g. { .. }).  Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var flattenedListOfPairs = listOfPairs.Select(pair => 
                                                  {
                                                      var list = new List<int>(pair.First);
                                                      list.AddRange(pair.Second));
                                                      return list;
                                                  }.ToList();
```